# minimum value in a dataset - cell2mat results in zero values

Tags: matlab

I am loading a dataset and I am taking user input to find the column values for a specific city.

For example:

```
city=input('Select city : ','s');
result=data(ismember(data.CITY,eval('city')),3:end);
```

and I am receiving :

Y2000  Y2002  Y2003 ..

100       120     150

Or if the user inputs the year:

```
year=input('Select year  : ','s');
result=data(:,{'CITY',eval('year')});
```

Now , I want to find the mimimum value inside "result" but I can't figure how.

Also,if I do  :

> min(data.Y2000)

in the entire data it works.But if I try min(data.year) , where

```
 year=input('Select year ','s')
```

I receive

> "Unrecognized variable name 'year'."

---------------UPDATE-----------------------------------------------------

For all the above I did:

```
 result=data(:,{'CITY',(year)});
```

In order to find minimum I did :  `min(result.(year));` and it works.

I have a problem with :

```
result=data(ismember(data.CITY,(city)),3:end);
```

I receive date with the year that the user selected.I want to find minimum values in all the columns.Because 'result' is a dataset I tried to make it a cell and then the cell matrix.

I used dataset2cell and then I receive a cell which size is 2x22 which contains characters in the 1st row. (it has 'Y200' , 'Y2001'..) and number data in thw 2 row.

In order to  delete the characters ,  I did:

> mycell(any(cellfun(@(x)x(1)=='Y', mycell),2), :) = []

and then :

> new=cell2mat(mycell)

because I want to find min and max values .

But this results in half of the values to be zero.

What can I do to prevent this?Or if there is another way to find min.

Comment: Consider using [dynamic field names](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/13/use-dynamic-field-references/) (i.e. `min(data.(year))` and `strcmp` to check for string equivalence - there shouldn't be a need for `eval` at all here.

Comment: @tmpearce:That was great!The "min(data.(year))" worked!I can't manage though when I select the city and it gives me all the columns with the years ,to find the min.

Comment: @tmpearce: I mean  I want "min(result)".The min(result.Y2000) works but how to take the minumum from the entire result?Also, please make this an asnwer.Thanks!

Comment: @tmpearce:last one!Also ,if my result has 2 columns .One with the city names and one with data for year 2000.How can I find the city which correspons to min value.Because I know the " [row,col] = find(result == max(result(:)));" but it doesn't work here..

Comment: Instead of `eval('city')`, why don't you just type `city`?

Comment: @tmpearce:Ok , have found all.I can't find only how to find the minimum from the whole result as I said above..

Comment: Would you mind to reformulate your concerns in a more comprehensive way, perhaps including some detailed study case? thanks in advance.

Comment: @fpe:Ok , i will do it in a moment.i will update